# assigning relationships between tables using common filelds in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, visual-paradigm

1. Hi , Here my scenario is too create the relationship between the
   existing tables which are not having/not defined any relation but
   having common field names in multiple tables of database .

   is there any tool to generate/achieve above explained scenario.

Comment: Can you give an example of such scenario? Like which table you have, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure , I have table T1,T2 . In that , let us take id, name , sal are three fields of the first table and Sid, id, department, category are the fields of second table . But I didn't defined any relationship between the tables , now I would like to achieve relationship between tables using common fields . Here , in this example , id will be the common key in both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.Name, T1.sal, T2.Sid, T2.department, T2.category
FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2
```

This will join the tables on the common field(s), leaving only the rows where they both have the same value(s) on the field(s).

Comment: Hi , thanks for the solution .In my database there are 800 tables are existed and out of 800 at least 100 tables are transnational   tables . it will be tedious task to join tables as per above technique.

Comment: No, I need a tool , so that it could be read the structure of database as well as assign relationship between the tables .

Comment: Basically what you need is a tool that scans your tables, looks for common fields among them and creates a relationship if necessary? I don't think there's a tool for that, but I have to admit that I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Okies, let us see ....we will get answers soon on this forum and pls share it in your contacts in this forum....